# "Rolling back" error states in Ember template

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

My Ember controller reaches out to a JSONAPI service (using Ember Data) like so:

```
    model: function(params) {
        return Ember.RSVP.hash({
            data: this.store.query('recipe', params),
            ...
        });
    },
```

The `params` can contain a filter string that, if malformed, will cause the server to respond with HTTP code 422. I catch this in the same controller like so:

```
    actions: {
        error: function(error, transition) {
            console.log('Retrieval error: ' + error.message);
            this.controller.set('filterValid', false);
        }
    }
```

And in my handlebars template, I can then check the `{{filterValid}}` property of my controller and optionally apply a style to the `<input>` tag, informing the user of the error.

**However:** Once the `filterValid` property has been set to false, I cannot seem to find the right action or hook to then rollback/reset the property to `true` when the query *doesn't* fail. Since the above code is in my *route*, I don't have direct access to the controller in the `model` function. (Nor, based on the model/controller/template diagrams I've seen, *should* I.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you maybe looking for the `setupController` hook. Which receives the resolved model and the controller.

```
setupController: function(controller, model) {
   this._super(controller, model);
   controller.set('filterValid', true);
}
```

I'm not sure if the method is called when an error occurs, (I would guess it's not called), but as you only need to set the flag when things go ok. I think this will work for you.

Comment: Glad it helped! Good luck with your ember app!